# How to get the index of row itself

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

Here is a DF for example

```
index  A     B     C      D(new Column)
   0   1     2     3      ?
   1   11    22    33     ?
   2   111   222   333    ?
```

Now, i want to apply a new(D) column to this DF depends on A column

if A column=1 apply B column's value(NOT LIST JUST VALUE) as new col
if A column=11 apply C column's value(NOT LIST JUST VALUE) as new col....

Firstly, I tried but it return me a LIST(Series) not the value; So i tried to locate it by index, but i need to get the index of each row, and use it to locate the value(may be I wrong)

So, what is the easiest way to do it?

Comment: can you provide the explicit expected output for clarity?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you need [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
df['D'] = np.select([df['A'].eq(1), df['A'].eq(11)], # list of conditions
                    [df['B'], df['C']],              # list of replacements
                    -1)                              # fallback value
```

output:

```
index    A    B    C   D
    0    1    2    3   2
    1   11   22   33  33
    2  111  222  333  -1
```

Alternative with a mapping dictionary and [lookup indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-lookup):

```
mapper = {1: 'B', 11: 'C'}

import numpy as np
idx, cols = pd.factorize(df['A'].map(mapper).fillna('missing'))
df['D'] = df.reindex(cols, axis=1).to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), idx]
```

output:

```
   index    A    B    C     D
0      0    1    2    3   2.0
1      1   11   22   33  33.0
2      2  111  222  333   NaN
```

Comment: Thank you very much! i am going to try later. Honestly, i thought that should be very easy from begaining....